# How to read barcode png in barby rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm try gem [barby](https://github.com/toretore/barby) for generate barcode png and works perfectly. Now I have problems reading my png barcode to make sure this barcode is valid.

How can I read a barcode png in gem barby rails?

Comment: You cannot read them back in, but instead you could use [zxing.rb](https://github.com/ecin/zxing.rb). It claims to be able to handle both 1D and 2D (QR Code) barcode image files.

Comment: hi @KenY-N, zxing.rb not working on heroku because this gem using jruby... whether you know gem decode barcode png with pure ruby?